# Safari - overlapping boxes on mobile flag page

Tags: bug, design, flags, mobile-web

On Safari when I went to my flag summary I noticed the Rude or Abusive and Pending boxes overlapped each other:

[image: overlapping]

This doesn't happen with other flags like Not an Answer of Low Quality as they don't have boxes. Only the Spam and Rude or Abusive have the red boxes and hence overlap.

Using Safari on iPhone on iOS 12.

Comment: Looks stylish :)